# How do i get a dictionary appended into a list without overlapping the exitsting dictionary json

Tags: python, json, forms, dictionary, flask

Im writing the code with Python, JSON and flask
Ive made a function "make_user():" to take data from my form and insert it into a dictionary:

```
users_list = []
@app.route("/makeuser", methods=["post"])
def make_user():
    firstname = f.request.form["firstname"]
    lastname = f.request.form["lastname"]
    username = f.request.form["username"]
    password = f.request.form["pwd"]
    mail = f.request.form["email"]
    car = f.request.form["car"]

    res = {
        "firstname" : firstname,
        "lastname" : lastname,
        "username" : username,
        "password" : password,
        "mail" : mail,
        "car" : car
    }
```

Where the trouble comes is when i try to open my json file, then add the existing dictionaries to the users_list and then append the input from the form, then dump the new list to the json file.
This is my try:

```
file = open("users.json", "r+")
users_list.append(file)

for list_item in users_list:
    users_list.append(res)

json.dump(users_list,file)
file.close

return redirect(url_for("form"))
```

what i want to have in the json file is a list with list items as dictionarys like so: [{},{},{},{}]

Any ideas to how i fix this?

Comment: Does `users.json` only contain a `dict` at the top level or is it a `list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
file = open("users.json", "r+")
users_list.append(file)
```

`file` here does not contain the contents of `users.json`. It's a "handle" to an open file that you can read data from -- or pass to `json.load`.

```py
for list_item in users_list:
    users_list.append(res)
```

This bit is nonsensical. Assuming you correctly loaded the contents of `users.json` this would append `res` to each element. Not only is that not what you want, it's not possible as each element is a dict.

Since you're replacing the contents of the file you need to open it twice; once for reading and once for writing. You can't append to the file because that will break the structured JSON. Try something like this:

```py
with open("users.json") as file:
    users_list = json.load(file)

users_list.append(res)

with open("users.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(users_list, file)
```

Comment: here i get this error code with debug=True on:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Start with `users.json` containing only `[]`

Comment: Niiiiice! It works now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `load` the data from the `json` file.

```
with open("users.json", "r") as file:
    try:
        users_list = json.load(file) # This should be your saved json structure
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: # in case your file does not contain valid json or is empty
        users_list = []
if isinstance(users_list, dict): # this can be removed if your top level is a list
    users_list = [users_list]
users_list.append(res) # append to the existing list
with open("users.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(users_list, file) # dump back to file
```

Let's say this is what is in your file.

```
{
    "firstname" : "Martin",
    "lastname" : "Mouse",
    "username" : "mmouse",
    "password" : "hunter9",
    "mail" : "mmouse@dasney.com",
    "car" : "Lambo"
}
```

The `json` module has a convenience function that reads your file from data and parses it into python objects in one step.

```
users_list = json.load(file)
```

This is essentially saying:

```
user_list = {
    "firstname" : "Martin",
    "lastname" : "Mouse",
    "username" : "mmouse",
    "password" : "hunter9",
    "mail" : "mmouse@dasney.com",
    "car" : "Lambo"
}
```

The next step is to make sure your top level is a `list` and if not make it so.

```
if isinstance(users_list, dict):
    users_list = [users_list]
```

So now your structure looks like this.

```
[
    {
        "firstname" : "Martin",
        "lastname" : "Mouse",
        "username" : "mmouse",
        "password" : "hunter9",
        "mail" : "mmouse@dasney.com",
        "car" : "Lambo"
    }
]
```

At this point you can append your new entry.

```
users_list.append(res)
```

Which is now this.

```
[
    {
        "firstname" : "Martin",
        "lastname" : "Mouse",
        "username" : "mmouse",
        "password" : "hunter9",
        "mail" : "mmouse@dasney.com",
        "car" : "Lambo"
    },
    {
        "firstname" : "Darnold",
        "lastname" : "Duck",
        "username" : "dduck",
        "password" : "hunter10",
        "mail" : "dduck@dasney.com",
        "car" : "Ferrari"
    }

]
```

And finally, dump back to file.

```
with open("users.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(users_list, file) # dump back to file
```

Comment: this works, but it just makes a list beside a list like so:
[{},{},{}][{},{},{}][{},{},{}]

Comment: i get an error message saying this is the problem:
users_list = json.load(file) # This should be your saved json structure

Comment: That would happen if what's in your file is not valid `json`. You could start with `[]` as @Woodford suggested.